# How to map file name to mounted device linux using C api

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

The problem I'm trying to solve:
I have a file name (with full path). I want to determine on what device on /dev/ it is located.
Is it possible to solve using linux C API?

Answer (score 1):

You can call any of the [`stat()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) family functions. They fill a `struct stat` with a lot of values, one of them, `st_dev`, is the device identifier of the block device that contains the file.

How can you map that to the real device? Well, you can iterate over all the devices in `/dev/*` and call `stat()` on all of them. The device that they represent is returned in this other field `st_rdev` (non POSIX); the one that matches the `st_dev` of the original file, that is the device you are looking for.

If instead, you want the *major* and *minor* numbers of the device, there are these other functions: [`major()` and `minor()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/major), that I think are not POSIX.